# LWC issue with checking validity of masked text field

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation

I'm having an issue with checking the validity of a field where I'm masking the input value (a credit card number).  The field has a `min-length` of 15.  When I remove focus from the field, the field correctly reports when the value is too short:

[image]

However, when I click on the **[Submit]** button, the JS code that does a `reportValidity()` and a `checkValidity()` on that field always returns true:

[image]

The strange thing is, the field field validity check accepts any input over 4 characters, which is much less than the minimum length specified.  Why do `reportValidity()` and `checkValidity()` consider the field value as being valid?

testAccountNumber.html

```
<template>

    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-var-m-bottom_small mainDiv">

        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-var-m-bottom_medium">
            <div class="slds-var-p-top_xx-small">Card Number</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-var-m-bottom_medium">
            <lightning-input 
                type="text" 
                name="cardAccountNumber" 
                label="Card Number"
                variant="label-hidden" 
                value={cardAccountNumber} 
                onfocusin={handleCardAccountNumberFocusIn}
                onchange={handleCardAccountNumberChange}
                onfocusout={handleCardAccountNumberFocusOut} 
                onkeydown={handleCardAccountNumberKeyDown} 
                class="creditCardAccountNumber requiredInput"
                min-length="9"
                max-length="16" 
                autocomplete="off"
                required>
            </lightning-input>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-clearfix buttons">
            <div class="slds-float_right">
                <lightning-button 
                    variant="brand-outline" 
                    label="Submit" 
                    title="Submit"
                    onclick={handleSubmit} 
                    class="submitButton">
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>
```

testAccountNumberField.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

const isAllowedKeyCode = keyCode => {
    if(keyCode === 8 // backspace
        || keyCode === 9 // tab
        || keyCode === 16 // shift
        || keyCode === 35 // end
        || keyCode === 36 // home
        || keyCode === 37 // left arrow
        || keyCode === 39 // right arrow
        || keyCode === 46 // delete
        ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const maskAccountNumber = value => {

    if(value === undefined || value === null || value === "") {
        return value;
    }

    let v = value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    let str = v.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");

    return str;
}

export default class TestAccountNumberField extends LightningElement {

    @api cardAccountNumber;
    @api actualCardAccountNumber;

    get isNewAccount() {
        return true;
    }

    handleCardAccountNumberFocusIn(event) {
        this.cardAccountNumber = this.actualCardAccountNumber;
    }

    handleCardAccountNumberChange(event) {
        let value = event.detail.value;

        console.log('handleCardAccountNumberChange', 'value:', value);
        this.actualCardAccountNumber = value.replace(/\D/g,'');

        this.cardAccountNumber = value;
        event.target.value = value;

        let cardAcctNumField = this.template.querySelector(".creditCardAccountNumber");
        cardAcctNumField.checkValidity();
        cardAcctNumField.reportValidity();
    }

    handleCardAccountNumberFocusOut(event) {

        console.log('handleCardAccountNumberFocusOut');

        let newValue = maskAccountNumber(this.cardAccountNumber);
        this.cardAccountNumber = newValue;

        const evt = new CustomEvent("card_account_number_change", {
            detail: {actualCardAccountNumber: this.actualCardAccountNumber, cardAccountNumber: this.cardAccountNumber}
            , bubbles: true
            , composed: true
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

    }

    handleCardAccountNumberKeyDown(event) {
        if(isAllowedKeyCode(event.keyCode)) {
            return;
        }

        if(!event.key.match(/[0-9]/)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.validateFields();
    }

    @api
    validateFields() {

        const allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('.requiredInput')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputFields) => {
                inputFields.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputFields.checkValidity();
            }, true);

        alert('validateFields(): ' + allValid);

        return allValid;
    }

}
```

webcomponents.dev [example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/wtVmtmBiQTEERuX4tesD/src/app.js?p=stories)